# Populating sms on Android Chrome just stopped working

Tags: android, google-chrome, sms

I've been using the

sms:555-555-1212;?&body=Hello

syntax to provide links to send pre-populated text messages. Worked in production for 20+ iOS/Chrome/Samsung users for over a year.

A few days ago it stopped working on Android Chrome. (Haven't heard from my iOS/Samsung users). As late as 2/26/19 it was working on my phone.... reloaded the page and then it wasn't.

No I haven't recently changed the page it's on. I've tried all possible permutations of single and paired ";", "?" and "&" without any luck. Yes the message is escaped properly. It still pops a new text message to the right number.... but it no longer populates the body text into it. Haven't checked if it's now limited to address book--my use case needs to work for non-address-book. (No, not a text spammer :-)

The "all three" and "? only" versions verified to still work on Android Firefox. Don't have iOS or Samsung devices handy for testing.

Anything else I should try before herding cats, er users into installing Firefox?

Comment: You sort this out, what was the solution?